# Incorrect flash movie behavior inside iframe and frameset in Internet Explorer

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, iframe, hashchange, deep-linking

I am investigating issue with odd behavior of a flash movie placed in a HTML frameset (or iframe) in the Internet Explorer 9.
If open index.html (http://melnishyn.narod.ru/ppt2swf/index.html) the movie shows its first frame for a short time and then jumps for empty white frame.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01Frameset//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Presentation</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src='frame.html' width="400" height="300">
    </body>
</html>
```

The movie displays correctly when open the frame.html (http://melnishyn.narod.ru/ppt2swf/frame.html) directly, however I noticed that when I change movie's frame (by its built in navigation buttons or mouse click), it somehow adds hash to the url (in IE only) so that it becomes http://melnishyn.narod.ru/ppt2swf/frame.html#Slide1

**frame.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01Frameset//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Frame</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.embedSWF("Holidays.swf", "FlashContainer", "400", "300", "10.2.0", "playerProductInstall.swf", {}, {width:'100%', height:'100%', allowScriptAccess: 'always'}, {});
            swfobject.createCSS("#FlashContainer", "display:block;text-align:left;");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="FlashContainer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In other browsers (Opera 12 and Firefox 14) everything works well.

The movie is produced from a presentastion (MS Power Point's ppt file) by a converter so I have no access to its source (other than decompiling it).

I am thinking of two possible workarounds - one of using a wrapper swf and second to use javascript setTimeout to constantly setting movie to required slide
with GotoFrame method. However both workarounds are undesired.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Try removing "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd" from DOCTYPE. It worked for me with some other frames and IE9 related issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.